# Server won't boot from flashstick

Tags: boot, server, grub2

I installed Ubuntu Server on my USB stick. When I try to boot (I go into BIOS and choose the stick specifically to boot from), I just get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I have tried holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, as I saw suggested on some other threads via Google search, but nothing does anything.

I assume **GRUB** is somehow messed up. I installed a driver onto Windows to let me view **ext4** file systems but I don't really know what I'm looking for.

### root directory:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu Server on your computer? How did you copy the iso image to your USB stick? Did you use the `dd` command to get that done?

Comment: I installed it to a flashstick with Pendrivelinux on Windows 10, then ran the installer after booting.  I made Linux install itself to the flashstick, and then when the question of where to put Grub came up, I asked it to make the flashstick bootable.  I am wondering if Ubuntu server is really necessary.  Can I just run a server on Debian or Mint?  Seems simpler, as a beginner (I'm only wanting to host a server to teach myself how it works).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Try according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). It shows a straightforward way to install a portable Ubuntu Server into an external drive, for example a USB pendrive or an SSD connected via USB.